# How to define regex for masking all words which contain "password"

Tags: regex, logging, logback, spring-logback

I use logback (logback-gelf) to log in my spring boot application. It has configuration xml file and I try to write regular expression to mask all words containing "passwords".

In configuration file. I write this:

```
%replace(%msg){'(?i)(password"\S+?")(\S+?)(".+)', '$1****$3'}  //I use (?i) for case insensitiveness
```

It works but only for one password in a log. For example if my log like this:

```
{"oldPassword":"123456","password":"654321"}
```

It convert it to:

```
{"oldPassword":"****","password":"654321"}
```

I want to mask all words which contain password.

How can I do this?

By the way it works on online regex tester but don't works on logback-spring

[online regex example](https://regex101.com/r/09nI3a/1)

Comment: Just FYI, `.+` looks redundant.

Comment: Does [this](https://regex101.com/r/M1yOiB/1) help?

Comment: @BurakKurhan Please copy and paste the solution into an answer and give it Best Answer so that it doesn't show in the search when people are looking for unanswered questions.  You will get `+2` points for doing so.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me @GirkovArpa.

I answered question and marked as a best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?i)(password"\S+?")(\S+?)"`

This works for me.

Thanks @JvdV for helps.